# Extract data from fillable pdf swift

Tags: swift, pdfview

I need to extract the data that is typed into a fillable pdf in swift. When I try to retrieve the data using `pdf.string` I get the text right before and after the fillable box but not the text in the box. Does anyone know how to get the data in the fillable box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been a while but I found the answer in case anyone else finds this useful. My annotations are of the widget variety.

```
for annotation in page.annotations {
    print(annotation.widgetStringValue)
}
```